# Installing s3fuse on Ubuntu ( bitnami ec2)

Tags: ubuntu, s3fs

I am installing s3fs-fuse on Ubuntu 14.04 ( Bitnami - EC2). 
Actually I want to mount S3 bucket. 
I installed the required dependencies successfully by running following command

```
apt-get install build-essential libfuse-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev mime-support automake libtool
```

Rest of the procedure mentioned as below

```
cd /tmp
wget https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/archive/v1.77.tar.gz
mv v1.77.tar.gz s3fs-fuse-1.77.tar.gz
tar zxvf s3fs-fuse-1.77.tar.gz
cd s3fs-fuse-1.77/
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
make install
```

while "make" (2nd last step) i am getting for following error

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `ldap_sasl_bind@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `ldap_get_dn_ber@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `ber_sockbuf_add_io@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `ldap_unbind_ext@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `ldap_get_attribute_ber@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `ldap_parse_result@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `ldap_set_option@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `ldap_abandon_ext@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `ldap_msgfree@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `ldap_result@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `ldap_search_ext@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `ldap_get_option@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `ber_memfree@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `ldap_memfree@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `ldap_pvt_url_scheme2proto@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `ldap_next_message@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `ber_free@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `ldap_err2string@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `ldap_init_fd@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `ldap_msgtype@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `ldap_free_urldesc@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `ldap_url_parse@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `ldap_first_message@OPENLDAP_2.4_2'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [s3fs] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/s3fs-fuse-1.80/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/s3fs-fuse-1.80'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

According to [github-s3fs-fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/wiki/Installation-Notes) you can install `s3fs` through the following steps:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git libfuse-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev mime-support automake libtool
sudo apt-get install pkg-config libssl-dev
git clone https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse
cd s3fs-fuse/
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/usr --with-openssl
make
sudo make install
```